# How can I create a script that retrieves the transaction history of an address and organizes the information on excel?

Tags: etherscan, nodes, infura, external-api

I have address 0x389505f098a29a994A3ed0e674f07cd451dde42C and I need to create an excel spreadsheet containing all the transactions from 2022 (roughly 40,000). Cannot download the csv report from etherscan since the limit is 5,000 transactions and I am not a fan of this method.

I was trying to use the api from https://ethblockexplorer.org/ however it is unable to load all the transactions. I now created an account with infura to use their more reliable api, but I am not sure how to around this since I failed with my last attempt.

The script is meant to run on my CLI only, where the input is an excel file with two columns "Asset" & "Address." When I run the program, the program should prompt the date range I am interested in and the output is another excel file organized in the following columns: Date, Block Index, Sent, Received, & Asset.

I am writing the script in python. Can someone give me a hand with this?

Comment: ChatGPT is great for use case like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moralis Transaction API to get all the transactions of an address.

Here is an example: https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-all-transactions-of-an-address.

Let me know if you need any help!

Disclosure: I work at Moralis